# Email not unique?

Tags: members, email, validation

Is there a way to remove the validation for unique email addresses.

I got a customer with a lot of members that must be imported into EE. But a lot of members doesn`t have a email address and a lot of duplicated email addresses are present.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing to do would be to create a fake email address for each member. The easiest way I can think of to do this would be via a small PHP script (might even be possible in Excel) that iterates a counter and inserts "user*n*@fakemail.com" into the relevant "slots" of your data source. Then import that into ExpressionEngine.

Comment: If you do this, use example.com rather than anything else, since example.com is a reserved domain name that no-one is allowed to own.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't know that. Top tip!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think, EE provides such a feature as email is mandatory field for member registration but it can be achieved by hack into EE's library file .

If you look within /system/expressionengine/libraries/Validate.php around line number 365 there is a function validate_email().

Within this function, you can comment the code which is checking for duplicate and empty email which are within the if conditions:

```
if ($this->email == '')
{
......
}

if ( ! valid_email($this->email))
{
.....
}

if ($type == 'new')
{
....
....
}
```

Its your preference if you would like to use hack because applying this hack duplicate and empty email will not be checked for all member registration process.

Answer (score 0):

You could try importing members directly into your database. After fiddling around with Laisvunas' Social Sign On add-on [it turns out that an e-mail being unique isn't really necessary](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/support/social-sign-on/viewthread/7239). You'll have to keep *something* unique, however, at least their username. You'll also have to bear this stuff in mind in regards to how members might be logging in... this eliminates their email address as a means of logging in as it is no longer unique.

The tricky part with this is then updating other tables (see below) to match the member's new `member_id` (in other words you wouldn't be able to just do an import, it would have to be scripted in part at least).

A quick google for required fields/tables for importing members directly into your EE database (matches what I find in relative add-ons):

> [I want to import my members. What is the minimum information that I need to populate in the database?](http://streetwise.emailstar.com/message/reply.lasso?MessageID=57)
>
> - group_id - the ID number for the member group this user belongs to
> - username
> - screen_name - can be identical to the username
> - password - can be MD5 or SHA1
> - unique_id - a random 32 character string, used for session cookies.
> - ip_address
> - join_date - Unix time stamp correlated to GMT time.
> - email
>
> There are two additional tables that must contain a row for each member, correlated with the member_id of the member:
>
> - exp_member_data
> - exp_member_homepage